# why does cocos2d-x version 4.0 not have macro CCARRAY_FOREACH?

Tags: c++, data-structures, visual-studio-2019, cocos2d-x

I can't find macro CCARRAY_FOREACH but i found CCARRAYDATA_FOREACH. Are those the same ? I mean can i use CCARRAYDATA_FOREACH instead?
And i tried but visual studio gives me an error of expression must have pointer type when i was using CCARRAYDATA_FOREACH and i can't solve. Any help would be appreciated.
Here is part of my code
void BaseManager::update(float dt){
auto visibleSize = Director::getInstance()->getVisibleSize();

```
Ref* obj = NULL;
Coin* coin = NULL;

int setNum = 0;
CCARRAYDATA_FOREACH(m_coinArr,obj){    // this line produces error: expression must have pointer type
    coin = (Coin*)obj;

    if(coin->getPositionX() < -coin->getConSize().width/2){
        coin->setVisible(false);
    }

    if( !coin->isVisible() ){
        setNum ++;
    }

    coin->setPositionX(coin->getPositionX()-map_speed);
}
```

................

Comment: What documentation says about these macroses?

Comment: as i read some pages, CCARRAY_FOREACH is used for looping through each object inside a CCArray. Maybe you can check it's defination on this page https://cocos2d-x.org/reference/native-cpp/V3.0alpha0/df/db3/group__data__structures.html. Roll your mouse down and you will see it.

Comment: You provided the link to version 3.0 alpha, but you use version 4, that's right?

Comment: Yeb, actually i can't find document for ver 4.0

Comment: Have you tried to search it? https://docs.cocos2d-x.org/api-ref/cplusplus/v4x/

Comment: That's such an useful thing i'am looking for.Thank so much for your help